# how to remove bottom gray bar from Three20's TTThumbsViewConroller?

Tags: xcode, uinavigationbar, thumbnails, three20, ttthumbsviewcontroller

I'm using Three20 for a viewing Thumbnails of Pictures in an album. everything works fine but i'm not able to remove the Gray bar at the bottom of the Navigation Bar.
Anyone who knows how to remove this bar?

[image]

Comment: As a side note, don't use Three20, its a bad framework, even the framework's creator has abandoned it as rubbish.

Comment: Shizam, Any better way to display albums and pictures in each albums? Gallery Style.

Comment: If you're targeting iOS 6.x and above I highly suggest UICollectionView, if you want to target older iOS versions check out AQGridView.  You'll have to do a little work to get them setup but its well worth it.

Comment: three20 is not a bad framework. it's just not maintained anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it. had to disable sections in tableView. 
Thanks Shizam i'm trying AQGridView as alternative.